# Apple Developer Account enrollment language

Tags: apple-id, developer-program, applecare

I'm trying to get enrolled to apple developer program so i can publish my apps on the app store, currently i live in Turkey so whenever i open the enrollment page to pay 100 USD the website redirects me to the Turkish version and change the currency to Turkish Lira, i don't speak Turkish and i don't want my account to be in Turkish, so my question is: **will i be stuck with a Turkish developer account or i can change the language after i pay ?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Rather than complaining about people who have no obligation to answer your question not answering your question, make sure you tag your question appropriately so it can be found by those who may be able to answer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that it doesn't matter, you can have English tools and documentations.

And i'm very frustrated with the users of this website. No one answered ?! not even comment.